# Full Screen Image Scaling on Mobile

Tags: html, css, image, mobile, responsive-design

I am working on a site where the homepage consists of a header (about 200px in height) and full-screen slider (which takes up the remaining space in the browser). As usual all is well on desktop and tablet views, but I can't seem to get the proportions correct for mobile devices. The images are set via the background-image property and I have already played around with the background-size, max-width, height, overflow, etc. properties and I am all out of ideas. I can maintain the proper proportions via max-width: 100%, height: auto, background-size: cover and the like but I end up with empty space at the bottom of the image.

To add to this the images being used are 1500 x 600 originally (for now), so even with mobile scaling proportionately the content within the image becomes hard to read.

[You can see the site here](http://factor1.me/2015/xico)

i have search around the web and haven't really found a suitable answer yet, and I am out of ideas on how to scale these images properly as well as continue to have them take up the remaining space in the browser - all while keeping the focus area of the image centered on the content. I am aware of JS plugins that can help with this problem, but I am opting for a CSS approach because the images will be sourced from WordPress uploads.

I'm stuck, so any feedback from the community would be appreciated!

Comment: I don't really understant your problem, but did you play with vw and vh units ? They are well supported now and sometimes far easier to use than others. Coupled with background-size: cover this is powerful.

Comment: Yes I did, I guess the real issue I am trying to solve is that since the images have informational content as a part of them, like a flyer, getting the image to scale properly while keeping that content legible a mobile device and without having empty space at the bottom of the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more playing around I will just implement a system where there is a desktop image, and mobile images. Not what I wanted to do but the best thing to do in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

> set media query for image place in the container

in css

@media only screen and (max-width: 40em){

.hero-slide.slick-slide {

```
background-size: contain;
```

}

}

Comment: close, this yields a very similar result I was able to achieve. The image does scale properly but on mobile devices the content of the image is not legible, and on some devices there is blank space at the bottom of the screen

Comment: then you have to reduce the height of slider container for small devices